# want to display call same random values

Tags: php, html, sql

I am making a online quiz which have id opt1-opt4 and answer in database.

I am calling the questions using function

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "ashu","ashua");
$db=mysql_select_db("quiz",$con) or die(mysql_error());

$display = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM quiz ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 2");

if (empty($_POST['submit'])) {


echo "<form method=post action=".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].">";
echo "<table border=0>";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($display)) {

$id = $row["id"];
$question = $row["question"];
$opt1 = $row["opt1"];
$opt2 = $row["opt2"];
$opt3 = $row["opt3"];
$opt4 = $row["opt4"];
$answer = $row["answer"];

echo "<tr><td colspan=3><br><b>Q:$question</b></td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td><input type=radio name=q$id value=\"$opt1\">$opt1 </td></tr>";
echo"<tr><td> <input type=radio name=q$id value=\"$opt2\">$opt2     </td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td><input type=radio name=q$id value=\"$opt3\">$opt3 </td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td><input type=radio name=q$id value=\"$opt4\">$opt4 </td></tr>";

}

echo "</table>";
echo "<input type='submit' value='See how you did' name='submit'>";
echo "</form>";

}
```

now I want to display same random values for answer but I am unable to call same random values. 
the function for answer is

```
$display = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM quiz ORDER BY id");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($display))
{

$question = $row["question"];
$answer = $row["answer"];
 $q = $_POST["q$id"];

echo "<tr><td><br>$question</td></tr>";

if ($q == $answer) 
    {
    echo "<tr><td>&raquo;You answered $q, which is correct</td></tr>";
    }
elseif ($q == "") {
echo "<tr><td>&raquo;You didn't select an answer. The Correct answer is $answer</td>     </tr>";
}
else {
echo "<tr><td>&raquo;You answered $q. The Correct answer is $answer</td></tr>";
}

}
echo "</table></p>";



}
```

How it is possible to get same random values in php
this display all the question from data base I want to dispaly only those which are genrated randomly

Answer (score 0):

The precise and short solution for you to display questions is to store all the questions in an array and either shuffle or rand the array with array `shuffle()` and `array_rand()` function.

Here is an example of `shuffle()` which you can use in your case.

In your `while{}` loop put all the $question = $row["question"] in an array

```
$randomize_questions = array($question);

shuffle($randomize_questions);

print_r($randomize_questions); //this will put all the questions in a random order
```

Then you can echo values from `$randomize_questions`

Comment: while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($display))

Comment: There are two while loops in which should I put these values

Comment: I want the same random values in next while loop is it possible